Flink Kafka connector timeout error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics
We are using FlinkKafkaconnector (v 3.3.0-1.20) with Flink 1.20. We have 2 jobs which are running in our flink k8s cluster, and while one of them is able to connect to kafka, the other one fails with the exception: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics.
Both of these jobs are using same Url to connect to our kafka. The connection mechanism is OAuth, and they are connecting to similar number of topics. We are not sure why one of the job fails and the other runs. (The failure seems to be rotating, sometimes one job fails, sometimes the other job fails). Below is the full stack trace:
2024-12-19 11:55:59
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailureAndReport(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:166)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.getGlobalFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:140)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleGlobalFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:324)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.lambda$failJob$0(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:669)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.lambda$handleRunAsync$4(PekkoRpcActor.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRunAsync(PekkoRpcActor.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:225)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.FencedPekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedPekkoRpcActor.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:174)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:33)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:545)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:229)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:280)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:253)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Global failure triggered by OperatorCoordinator for 'Source: Kafka Source -> Sink: Writer -> Sink: Committer' (operator cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2).
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.failJob(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:651)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator$QuiesceableContext.failJob(RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator.java:259)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.failJob(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:432)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.handleUncaughtExceptionFromAsyncCall(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:445)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to list subscribed topic partitions due to 
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.checkPartitionChanges(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$null$1(ExecutorNotifier.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:40)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get metadata for data\.us\.ca\.fl\.ab\.ce\..+ topics.
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:54)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.TopicPatternSubscriber.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(TopicPatternSubscriber.java:49)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:233)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$notifyReadyAsync$2(ExecutorNotifier.java:80)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:46)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics

Are there any settings that we can pass to the flink kafka connector or our kafka setup to fix this problem?
